# Unable to access the swagger document oof microservice through spring cloud gateway

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, microservices, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a spring cloud gateway with following configuration for account service

```
      routes:
        - id: account-service
          uri: lb://account-service
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/v1/account/**
```

I have configured the swagger UI as

```
springdoc:
  swagger-ui:
    urls:
      - name: account
        url: /v3/api-docs/account
```

My route definitions in application is

```
    @Bean
    public List<GroupedOpenApi> apis() {
        List<GroupedOpenApi> groups = new ArrayList<>();
        List<RouteDefinition> definitions = locator.getRouteDefinitions().collectList().block();
        assert definitions != null;
        definitions.stream().filter(routeDefinition -> routeDefinition.getId().matches(".*-service")).forEach(routeDefinition -> {
            String name = routeDefinition.getId().replaceAll("-service", "");
            System.out.println(name);
            System.out.println(routeDefinition.getUri());
            groups.add(GroupedOpenApi.builder().pathsToMatch("/api/v1/" + name + "/**").group(name).build());
        });
        return groups;
    }
```

While accessing the api docs of account service, i am getting below error
[image]

Getting below exception

```
2022-08-19 20:04:35.926 ERROR 26989 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [425c7746-6] 500 Server Error for HTTP GET "/v3/api-docs/document"

java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.web.cors.reactive.CorsWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WeightCalculatorWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/v3/api-docs/document" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Original Stack Trace:
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:276) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:233) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:223) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:356) ~[na:na]
        at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBuf.setBytes(PooledByteBuf.java:253) ~[netty-buffer-4.1.70.Final.jar:4.1.70.Final]
        at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1132) ~[netty-buffer-4.1.70.Final.jar:4.1.70.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:350) ~[netty-transport-4.1.70.Final.jar:4.1.70.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:151) ~[netty-transport-4.1.70.Final.jar:4.1.70.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:719) ~[netty-transport-4.1.70.Final.jar:4.1.70.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655) ~[netty-transport-4.1.70.Final.jar:4.1.70.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581) ~[netty-transport-4.1.70.Final.jar:4.1.70.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) ~[netty-transport-4.1.70.Final.jar:4.1.70.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986) ~[netty-common-4.1.70.Final.jar:4.1.70.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.70.Final.jar:4.1.70.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.70.Final.jar:4.1.70.Final]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
```